# Find if certain characters are present in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, find

I have the following code and want to see if the string 'userFirstName' contains any of the characters in the char array. If the string does I want it to ask the user to reenter their first name and then check the new name for invalid characters and so on.

```
char invalidCharacter[] = { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '~', '`',             
    ';', ':', '+', '=', '-', '_', '*', '/', '.', '<', '>', '?', ',', '[', ']', '{', '}',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

cout << "Please enter your first name: " << endl;
cin >> userFirstName;`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`string::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) to do it.

Assuming that `userFirstName` is a `string`:

```
size_t pos = userFirstName.find_first_of(invalidChars, 0, sizeof(invalidChars));
if (pos != string::npos) {
    // username contains an invalid character at index pos
}
```